# How to expose Visualforce pages in a lightning:tabSet?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

I'd like to put several Visualforce pages inside tabs of a `lighting:tabSet` so that I can expose those (somewhat) legacy pages as a set in a Lightning App.

What is the simplest way to do this?

Is there any way to vertically size the `lighting:tabSet` so that vertical scroll bars are avoided?

**PS**

Why I don't think this question is a duplicate of [Can you embed visualforce inside a lightning component?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/92656/can-you-embed-visualforce-inside-a-lightning-component):

- That has a hard-coded domain name in the URL: how can that be avoided?
- That has a hard-coded iframe height and so scroll bars will appear or the component will be taller than it needs to be; this question explicitly asks about that and Raul's comment points to a solution to that potentially being awkward
- That is using a HTML `iframe`; is that the way to go or is using `lightning:container`?
- The OP didn't accept an answer

Comment: I think this might help you https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/92656/can-you-embed-visualforce-inside-a-lightning-component?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Should be possible with use of an iFrame. For getting rid of vertical scroll bars, we could resize the height of iFrame after load. DOM manipulation with lightning is not very good also because of locker service, need to try if resize is allowed.